# Modify a column's size using Knex js

Tags: javascript, node.js, migration, knex.js

I would like to know if there is any way to modify a column size of a table using Knex.

I tried this in a migration file:

```
return knex.raw('alter table USERS modify PWDUSR VARCHAR(255)')
```

But it doesn't work. How can I fix this?

Comment: which database are you using? Are you really using upper case in your table names?

Comment: Yes, and I'm using Oracle 11g

Answer (score 1):

Try this to have identifier quoting to be set correctly for presumably uppercase table / column names:

```
return knex.raw('alter table ?? modify ?? VARCHAR(255)', ['USERS', 'PWDUSR'])
```